# Change Animation parent / link?

Tags: animation, dopesheet, actions

Is there a way to "re-parent" animation data? FYI, I don't know much about this, so I'm probably using the wrong term.

Basically, I unintentionally "parented" (or linked? not exactly sure if that word is right, but I see it in a lot of menus I'm trying to use) my animations to random meshes within my models.

See these screenshots:

[image: hierarchy view of animation]

[image: dope sheet view of animations]

My expectation (not sure if this is correct), is that all of my animations should "belong" to my top level Armature. Instead, I've got some (but not all) animations attached to various other parts, like a piece of the neck, and the left leg (???).

Not only was this unintentional / messy, it is causing problems down the line, as I'm exporting an FBX which is then imported into Unity. Then Unity seems confused itself, since animations belong to the neck instead of the Armature.

Is there a way to take my existing animations and make them belong to the top level armature? I was able to right click an "unlink" from the hierarchy, but then it appeared they weren't owned by anything, and weren't getting exported/imported.